# How can I change the style of the expand/collapse column for the detail tables of a Telerik AJAX RadGrid?

Tags: telerik, radgrid, telerik-ajax

I can change the backcolor of the actual expand/collapse control (Red in the example below), but I can't seem to figure out how to change the color of the extended area under it, when the detail tables are expanded.

In the attached image, I have indicated the area that I am trying to also change to red.

Can anyone explain how to do this?

[image]

Comment: I think it would be done with CSS - background colour setting and maybe a linear gradient removal for a suitable selector